# Is there a group for CNC routing?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking this on Meta because it clearly is off-topic for 3D printing, but there is enough in common someone here may know.

What is the SE group for CNC routers, such as the multitude of 4060, 4040, and 3018 routers on Amazon and eBay?  I'd like to find a community and find some guidance.

Comment: As an alternate, perhaps you can find help at https://www.cnczone.com/forums/ (no affiliation), which claims over half a million registered users.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one, at least not *specifically* for CNC. We are the closest to CNC stuff I believe.

You could try [SE.Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Or go to [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) and try to start a new group.